# Is there any tool that shows the order of files that gets run in a project?

Tags: python, linux

I am reading source code of a project that contains several sub-folders and files. I was wondering if there is any tool that shows the order of the files and/or functions that gets run in a project. The project is in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're asking for a list of the modules that get imported. To do that, use the `python -v` option for [verbose output](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-v).

> Print a message each time a module is initialized, showing the place (filename or built-in module) from which it is loaded. When given twice (-vv), print a message for each file that is checked for when searching for a module. Also provides information on module cleanup at exit.

That will give you a list of all the modules that get imported in the order they are imported.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [pycallgraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/en/master/)?

> Python module that creates call graph visualizations for Python
>   applications.

Additionally you can try [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/):

> Generate dependency graphs from Python code.